# Vlookup with multiple conditions (negative / maximum value in the array)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to create a VLOOKUP with condition to fill up columns G and H.

The algorithm/condition is something like this.

Target: Lookup M value from Column C, by matching the Node.

1. If Mz < 0, it goes to G (Take the Mininum value of Mz, i.e. largest negative Mz)
2. If Mz > 0, it goes to H (Take the Maximum value of Mz, i.e. largest positive Mz)

[image]

I tried to create an array formula `{=IF(MIN(VLOOKUP(F2,$B:$C,2,FALSE))<0,VLOOKUP(F2,$B:$C,2,FALSE),0)}`
But it doesn't seem to work properly.

Appreciate your enlightenment for this newbie. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is what you are showing the results of your formula?  Or your desired results?  If not the desired results, add some columns which show that.  For each node, will you positive and negative values always match, as you show in your example?  What version of Excel???

Comment: Hi @Pitbull999,, your formula with IF & VLOOKUP and If Mz < 0 alos If Mz > 0 logical test are contradicting each other,, plzz be clear and loud all about your need,, meanwhile I'm suggesting formula find MIN & MAX matching NODE in Col F in NODE in Col B,,, `{=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(F2,$B$2:$C$29,2,FALSE)<0,MIN($E$2:$E$11),MAX($F$2:$F$11)),"")}`,,, reply through comments ☺

Comment: Appreciate you guys for taking your time. Sorry if I wasn't very clear. I have re-attach a new picture to explain clearer.

@RonRosenfeld: Excel 2013. this may not be the best example because the value of +ve and -ve results looks identical for all nodes. But they are not always the case. That's why I required to lookup for the max / min values.

Comment: @RajeshS Please have a look on my new screenshot and let me know any further info you might need. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Pitbull999,, due to TIME ZONE I'm little late,, but now check my post below,, you find results as you were looking for .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your version of Excel:

```
Negatives:  =AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($F2=$B:$B)*$C:$C,1)
Positives:  =AGGREGATE(14,6,1/($F2=$B:$B)*$C:$C,1)
```

[image]

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot @Ron

Answer (score 0):

*This solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- An array (CSE) formula in cell D96:

  ```
  {=MIN(IF($A$96:$A$112=$C96,$B$96:$B$112))}
  ```
- An array (CSE) formula in cell E96:

  ```
   {=MAX(IF($A$96:$A$112=$C96,$B$96:$B$112))}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Used groups are 1 to 5, you may include more.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.
- **Another solution should be Pivot Table to Find Max/Min Value In A Group.**